# Anaconda module error … “no module named pip”

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-module, sublime-anaconda

When i try to install pymongo in anaconda it is showing the error. 
[image]
please help me to slove this

Comment: looks like you don't have `pip` installed: https://pypi.org/project/pip/

Comment: Please copy and paste text from terminal windows (indent using the code button); don't take a screenshot. That makes it easier for others to see the messages directly, and to cite them in answers.

Comment: sure from next time ill do that . Thanks for the advise @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 5):

Try install `conda install -c anaconda pip` then install the package or you can directly install `conda install -c anaconda pymongo`.

Comment: C:\Users\p#an!>conda install -c anaconda pip
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.       It is showing this error

Comment: Open anaconda prompt and run as admin, then try `conda update conda` or `conda update --all`, then try again installing the packages.  Take precaution when using pip, its better to check first if the package that you want to install is available on anaconda libraries, because sometimes it causes error. I usually use pip install to anaconda env if there is no available package on anaconda libraries.

Comment: Or you can install packages using anaconda navigator. Just lunch the app, then go to environments then search the packages you wish to install and select and apply.

Answer (score -1):

Phani Anaconda uses a module named `conda`. `pip` is not available for anaconda.